# October CMS - required checkbox

Tags: laravel, checkbox, octobercms

How could I validate if the checkbox is ticked?

```
public $rules = [
    'name' => 'required',
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'phone' => 'required',
    'terms' => 'required',
];
```

'terms' is the name of the checkbox. Now I get the alert about required field even if it is checked.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="terms" value="1" id="terms"/>
```

Simple HTML5 attribute required is also not working.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouter Van Damme has it right. You simply need to use the trait listed in that documentation. like so:

```
public $rules = [
    'name' => 'required',
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'phone' => 'required',
    'terms' => 'required|accepted',
];
```

here is an october specific link although the answers are the same.http://octobercms.com/docs/services/validation#rule-accepted

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same "field terms is required".

Checkbox HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/phntwrek/

Comment: This is a silly question, but your initial value is set 1 so when you click it are you setting it to 0? Also I don't really think you need required because accepted does the same thing essentially, you can't submit without it.